# webkit css endless rotation-animation not working. Why?

Tags: css, webkit

I am trying to spin a null set image but my code is not working.
If I ran on my own computer, the picture goes black and spin. 
What is the problem?

```
    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        from{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    #refresh {
        width:48px;
        height:48px;
        position:fixed;
        top:150px;
        right:150px;
        background:url(http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/41700/41726/fc_nullset_41726_lg.gif);
        -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
   }

<div id="refresh" ></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pg2pj/

Comment: It's working alright, you just don't see the white background of the .gif on the white background of jsfiddle. See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pg2pj/1/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work just fine. Here: http://cssdesk.com/6VyMM

Answer (score 0):

I updated your FIDDLE, have a look.

Hope this can help you

[image: jsFiddle]

---

You can also use percent in your animation instead of `from` and `to`

**CSS:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

#refresh {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: grey url(http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/41700/41726/fc_nullset_41726_lg.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

**Remember for cross-browser compatibility:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0%   {  }
  100% {  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  0%   {  }
  100% {  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotate {
  0%   {  }
  100% {  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0%   {  }
  100% {  }
}
```

---

```
#refresh {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear 0s infinite /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotate 2s linear 0s infinite /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotate 2s linear 0s infinite /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotate 2s linear 0s infinite /* IE 10+ */
}
```